# Resolution after reboot locked at 1024*768

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, hdmi, resolution

### Prestory

I bought a HDMI switch to switch between this win 10 PC and linux laptop. The switch is garbage and so I'll send the switch back.

### Setup

My win 10 machine is attached to my monitor with an HDMI Cable.
Every time I boot this machine the settings in the resolution field is 1024*768. There is only one other option: 800*600.
I have a GTX 970 installed with 388.13 (apperently newest) installed.

#### Stuff I figured out

If I attach this PC to a TV, the resolution jumps to 1920*1080. While running I I'll detach the cable from the TV to my Monitor and then I also the expected resolution of 1920*1080. But only for as long as I don't reboot the machine.

[image: Resolution Settings]
[image: Nvidia Administration pannel]

Comment: GTX 970 is listed in Device Manager as Display Adapter?

Comment: I guess so: https://imgur.com/a/XEqUy

Comment: Is your monitor properly recognized (installed)?

Comment: what do you mean with installed? The cables are all plugged in well. I only use only use good cables. If you mean Software-wise i did nothing, except for the nvidia drivers.

Comment: Problem is: or your monitor is not properly connected or your graphics card, even if recognized, is not working. I think you should try to uninstall your card's drivers, uninstall the card from Device Manager and then shut down and remove physically the card. 
After that start the PC and let Windows 10 load, then shut it down. Insert the card in place again and reconnect it, then start the PC and install updated Nvidia drivers.
It's worth trying. Good luck

Comment: Well, if it isn't any more then that I'll try it :D

Comment: If all of this doesn't fix the problem, I think you will have to save data, format disk and install Windows again. :(

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion spike_66. I had to reinstall Windows. I appreciate your effort!